# Which mathematical law is used in $ab+ac-(b+c)=(a-1)(b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, simple-functions

I just stumbled upon a question to figure out how to simplify

J = (a*b)+(a*c)-(b+c)

My steps:

<=> a*(b+c)-b-c

<=> a*(b+c) -1*(b+c)

But that was not one of the solutions. One of these was, as mentioned above,
(a-1)*(b+c).

As I saw this I somehow knew it is correct, calculated it and yes it is. But my math is a bit outdated and I cannot remember the law to see this. I do know it is correct, but by the love of god, I still don't know how to pull it of.

Comment: You are almost done. $a(b+c) -1(b+c)$ can be factored again (b+c) and will yield: $(a-1)(b+c)$

Comment: Your title has $+$ instead of $*$

Comment: aaah, now I see it. It is not any fancy rule, it is just another factorization. Something tree, something forest..
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called the [*distributive law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)
$$
(x+y)z=xz+yz.
$$
You apply it backwards in
$$
(a-1)\underbrace{(b+c)}_{z}=a\underbrace{(b+c)}_{z}-1\underbrace{(b+c)}_{z}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The first two terms are $a(b+c)$ by *distributivity of multiplication over addition*. A reuse of this rule, together with $x=1x$ with $x=b+c$, completes the proof.